# Comment on answer I didn't select

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments

Not sure if it was just me, but...

I just applied a comment, and it ended up against a different answer.

The answer that the comment ended up against didn't have the code in it that I was commenting on, and didn't show that it had been edited.

It may be that the answer I selected originally had been deleted as it wasn't on the list of answers any more.

The question involved is here: [Later-inserted tags not seen by JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990573/later-inserted-tags-not-seen-by-jquery), and the answer that ended up with the comment was eyurdakul's.

Could there be a bug here (it may just be me and not enough coffee this morning)?

Note: the comment is no longer there.

Comment: The comment that isn't there anymore was removed from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9990620/50049), when all comments were purged because of a spitball fight over revenge down voting, and allusions to drug use in replies. Doesn't shed light as to how your comment may have ended up on the wrong answer, but leaving some follow up breadcrumbs.

Comment: @TimPost: Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: And yeah, the comment you left was in no way applicable to the answer, which is why it (amongst many others) was deleted. It specifically mentioned `live()` being deprecated, but the answer it landed on didn't mention `live()`. However, the one directly [under it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9990601/50049) did .. is it possible you just mis-clicked?

Comment: @TimPost: Maybe, only thing with that is that I order by Oldest, and the others that refer to "Live" are nowhere near the answer it ended up on. I thought I'd raise it just incase there is some sort of issue around answers being added/deleted while comments are also being added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm 99.999999% sure you mis-clicked here, traffic logs show your comment with to the correct place, and this behavior hasn't changed in a very long time (which post it goes to is a fairly simple thing to determine).

Comment: Ok - fair enough. Thx for looking into it.

Comment: @Jon - Of course, it's what we're here for, that and free drinks :)

Comment: Where are these free drinks you speak of?

Comment: @TimPost - Let me know when you find out where they're hiding them

Comment: You misunderstand, @cdeszaq; the drinks are free _for Nick_. This round's on you.

Comment: (Before you ask, @TimPost is a mod, so he's exempt from paying.)

Comment: @PopularDemand - Damn me and my decaffeinated misunderstandings! I'll eventually learn not to touch a keyboard before 12oz.